# Vimscript function doesn't work

Tags: vim, escaping, macvim

Here is a function copied from others and modified to search the selected text in Visual Mode in Chrome on my MacOS:

```
function! GoogleSearch()
     let searchterm = getreg("g")
     exec ":!open -a Google\ Chrome \"http://google.com/search?q=" .searchterm . "\" &" 
endfunction
vnoremap <F6> "gy<Esc>:call GoogleSearch()<CR>
```

But it does nothing but outputs the command and saying that *"Press ENTER or type command to continue"*:
[image]

#### What I have tested

- Copy the whole command`:!open -a Google Chrome "http://google.com/search?q=silent" &` into command line the press  and it **works**
- Replace the third statement with `exec ":!open -a Google\ Chrome \"http://google.com/search?q=" .searchterm . "\""` and call it, it **failed**:[image]
- Test some system functions to escape the command string before exec it, such as **escape()**, **shellescape()**, they all **failed**.

So what's the problem here? Although there are some plugins offering this kind of function, but I want to figure out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: I believe you need to quote `"Google Chrome"`, so instead of  `:!open -a Google\ Chrome  \"url...`  try  `:!open -a \"Google Chrome\"  \"url...`. In addition, you can remove `<Esc>` from `vnoremap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Google Chrome is set as your default browser, you can simply remove the application call as long as your url is valid.

```
function! GoogleSearch()
     let searchterm = getreg("g")
     exec ":!open \"http://google.com/search?q=" .searchterm . "\" &" 
endfunction
vnoremap <F6> "gy<Esc>:call GoogleSearch()<CR>
```